# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host?

Tags: ssh, git

```
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/DAMS/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/DAMS/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/DAMS/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/DAMS/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Hello, this one is different. Nothing missing or anything. I am using cygwin and it just stops when I do `git push production` on my server. This is usually ok, but I wonder why it is stopping connections.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand the issue, but [this](https://gist.github.com/1180223) worked for me:

```
echo "sshd:ALL" >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

Depending on your system, you may need to `sudo` this.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the server is using tcp wrappers and your IP is not whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can start sshd in debug mode on your server to find out what's actually going wrong, but I have a pretty good feeling that your problem is that either your ~/.ssh directory or your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file is world-readable on the server.

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: btw there is no dir ~/.ssh or ~/.ssh authorized key. but yesterday it allwork fine.

Comment: bash: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory

Comment: authorized_keys2

Answer (score 0):

likely cannot write to /var/ area for process accounting. check for full or readonly file systems on the host system.

Comment: how can i do that ? on my server ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared keys it looks like either:

1. you haven't specified the correct private key; or
2. your public key is (no longer?) in your server's authorized_keys file; or
3. as jgoldshrafe suggests, the permissions on your authorized_keys file is incorre

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the connection was closed during the initial negotiation. I would guess that if you telnet to the server on port 22 that the connection is accepted and then closed again straight away?

Answer (score 0):

You can get "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" if your `sshd` service is not operational!

If you have access to the server check you have the `sshd` service running with:

```
  ps aux | grep ssh
```

and check it is listening on port 22:

```
 netstat -plant | grep :22
```

[more details here](http://www.ewhathow.com/2013/09/how-to-check-if-ssh-is-running-on-linux/)